References for Bernstein-Zelevisnky classification
I am looking for references for the Bernstein-Zelevisnky classification of irreducible representations of GL$(n,F)$ in terms of cuspidal representations. In particular I would like to find something different with respect to the article of the 1980 in which they explain it. Online there are few notes that speak about the classification but I didn't find anything with proofs.

Are you looking for references other than Zelevinsky's original paper Induced representations of reductive $\mathfrak p$-adic groups. II. On irreducible representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$?

@KentaSuzuki  Yes, I would like to find something else.

What is wrong about the original reference?

There isn’t any problem with the original reference, but I think to have other references can be useful.

There is an extension of this result which includes torsion coefficients (coprime to the residue characteristic of $F$) by Mínguez-Sécherre: Représentations lisses modulo $\ell$ de $\mathrm{GL}_n(D)$
Don't let the title confuse you, it also works in characteristic 0, also it is a purely algebraic proof, you find a discussion in the introduction of the paper.
